# \DeclareSortingTemplate with Overleaf

Tags: biblatex, biber, overleaf

I need to switch a project to Overleaf. I'm using `biblatex` and Biber, and I use `\DeclareSortingTemplate` to create a separate bibliography environment that's sorted by shorthand instead of author.

Is there a special package I need or....?

Minimal example that works in my regular setup but not on Overleaf:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@book{test,
  title      = {A Title},
  year       = {2420},
  author     = {Famous, Person},
  location      = {Big City},
  publisher  = {Fancy Academic Press},
  shorthand  = {b2420},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{example.bib}

% special sort style
\DeclareSortingTemplate{byShorthand}{
  \sort{\field{shorthand}}
  \sort{\field{name}}
  \sort{\field{year}}
  \sort{\field{title}}
}

\begin{document}
I want to cite \cite{test}

\newrefcontext[sorting=byShorthand]
\printbibliography[title={Bibliography sorted by shorthand}]

\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
\printbibliography[title={Bibliography sorted by author}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) New projects on Overleaf are currently created using TeX Live 2017, which includes an older version of `biblatex` than you're likely using. On TL2017, you should use `\DeclareSortingScheme` instead of `\DeclareSortingTemplate`. The syntax is the same, this macro was simply renamed in more recent versions of `biblatex`.

Comment: There is a predefined sorting template/scheme called `shorthand` that sorts only by `shorthand` and not by name, title and year. So you could just use `\newrefcontext[sorting=shorthand]` and no `\DeclareSortingTemplate` at all. The difference should be negligible unless you use the same `shorthand` twice (which you probably shouldn't). Note that `\field{name}` is not a valid sorting rule anyway, since there is no field called `name`.

Comment: Actually `\field{name}` is sort of valid in the current version of Biber (see https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/262), it just does not do something extremely useful. Unless there is a field called `name` it will behave like `\literal{name}`. But since it is in a `\sort{...}` of its own that means it could be omitted since all entries will have the "name" string in their sort specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Paul's comment above, I was able to fix this issue by using the (now deprecated) `\DeclareSortingScheme` (`biblatex` version <3.8) instead of `\DeclareSortingTemplate` (`biblatex` >= 3.8). As of this post, Overleaf uses TeX Live 2017 with `biblatex` 3.7 (2016/12/05) for new projects.

Working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@book{test,
  title      = {A Title},
  year       = {2420},
  author     = {Famous, Person},
  location      = {Big City},
  publisher  = {Fancy Academic Press},
  shorthand  = {b2420},
}
@book2{test2,
  title      = {A Title},
  year       = {2420},
  author     = {Author, Person},
  location      = {Big City},
  publisher  = {Fancy Academic Press},
  shorthand  = {c2420},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{example.bib}

% special sort style
\DeclareSortingScheme{byShorthand}{
  \sort{\field{shorthand}}
  \sort{\field{name}}
  \sort{\field{year}}
  \sort{\field{title}}
}

\begin{document}
I want to cite \cite{test} and \cite{test2}

\newrefcontext[sorting=byShorthand]
\printbibliography[title={Bibliography sorted by shorthand}]

\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
\printbibliography[title={Bibliography sorted by author}]
\end{document}
```

Edit: Furthermore, as pointed out by moewe above, I can use the pre-defined "sorting=shorthand" option. A much sleeker approach!