# \DeclareSortingTemplate: not working as expected

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, sorting

In the following MWE, I expect reference "B" to appear before "A" in the reference list, because `sortyear` should take priority over `year`. But I can't get that to happen after much tinkering... I've read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46868) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485516) questions and the corresponding section of biblatex manual without much help.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex,
  defernumbers=true,
  sorting=xxx,
]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mwe.bib}
  @article{A,
    title = {A},
    year = {1111},
    sortyear = {2222}
  }
  @article{B,
    title = {B},
    year = {2222},
    sortyear = {1111}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{mwe}\nocite{*}
\DeclareSortingTemplate{xxx}{
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
}
\begin{document}
  \printbibliography[resetnumbers=true]
\end{document}
```

Comment: PS: I'm fully cleaning .aux etc. files between every compile.

Comment: If I change `backend` to `biber` and add the .bib extension to `\addbibresource` it does produce expected results for me.

Comment: Thanks. Me too. Is bibtex incompatible with `\DeclareSortingTemplate`? I need other features of bibtex...

Comment: I don't really know, but it appears so... What the manual says about this is that for the `bibtex` `backend`:  "Sorting is global and is limited to us-ascii ordering". Which doesn't say anything about sorting templates.

Comment: Huh, thanks for that. I was actually able to switch to `biber` for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, with `backend=bibtex` you can only use a restricted list of sorting schemes (`none`, `nty`, `nyt`, `nyvt`, `anyt`, `anyvt`, `ynt`, `ydnt`, `debug`) and `\DeclareSortingTemplate` is not available at all with BibTeX.

You will need to use Biber with your document. (Which is a good idea anyway since many of `biblatex`'s advanced features require Biber. The documentation used to explain which bits were Biber-only, but a few years ago it was decided to make BibTeX a "legacy backend" and just assume that the average user uses Biber.)

https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/0c21cd8c142d1a2f0c2d1e4810890388fa82551e will give a warning in case unsupported sorting templates are used with BibTeX.